# How can I set up a route just for my Account controller in ASP MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following route:

```
http://127.0.0.1:81/Account/Login
```

My route controller looks like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Account",
            url: "Account/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account" } 
            );
```

Can someone tells me if this is the correct way to set up a route. Do I need to even specify defaults: new { controller = "Account" } ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify controller as well as action

```
       routes.MapRoute(
        "Account",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```